# VueJS does not update DOM after fetch data from API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create an example about the list of photos and I see a trouble when binding data to the component after call API.

**JS code:**

```
<script>
// photo item
Vue.component('photo-item', {
   props: ['photo'],
   template: `<li>{{ photo.name }}</li>`
});

// List of photos
Vue.component('photo-list', {
   props: ['photos'],

   template: `
   <ul id="photo-list">
      <photo-item v-for="photo in photos" :photo="photo"></photo-item>
   </ul>`
});

new Vue({
   el: "#photo_detail",
   data: {
      photos: []
   },

   created: function() {
      axios
       .get('/api/photos')
       .then(function (response) {
           this.photos = response.data; // Data existed
       })
       .catch(function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       });
   }
 })
 </script>
```

**HTML code**

```
<main id="photo_detail">
    <photo-list v-for="photo in photos" :photo="photo"></photo-list>
</main>
```

After fetching all photos from API and as my understand then the variable `photos` will auto binding and VueJS will update DOM.

**VueJs 2.1.6**

Any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Issue is with your `this` value inside `function()` which has this value scoped to `axios` instead of vue instance .
or you can use `(response)=>` to use `this` directly

```
new Vue({
   el: "#photo_detail",
   data: {
      photos: []
   },

   created: function() {
      var self=this;
      axios
       .get('/api/photos')
       .then(function (response) {
           self.photos = response.data; // Data existed
       })
       .catch(function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       });
   }
 })
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh...yeah, that great, so basic :D, thank you @Helping hand, close my issue :D

Comment: It works but gives this error: `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct.

Problems:

1. It will be better to define used components for each component, like
   `components: {photoItem}`.
2. In your axios callback you use `function` and that means, that you use wrong context inside (`this.photos`). Use arrow function
   (`() => {}`) instead of the `function () {}`
3. The directive `v-for` requires directive `:key=""`

I've fixed it below.

```js
// photo item
const photoItem = Vue.component('photo-item', {
   props: ['photo'],
   template: `<li>{{ photo.name }}</li>`
});

// List of photos
const photoList = Vue.component('photo-list', {

  // define used components
  components: {photoItem},
  props: ['photos'],
  template: `
   <ul id="photo-list">

      <!-- add :key="" directive -->
      <photo-item v-for="(photo, index) in photos" :key="index" :photo="photo"></photo-item>
   </ul>`
});


new Vue({
   el: "#photo_detail",

   // define used components
   components: {photoList},
   data: {
      photos: []
   },

   created: function() {

      // axios.get('/api/photos')
      // use arrow function
      setTimeout(() => {
  this.photos = [{name: 'Photo 1'}, {name: 'Photo 2'}];
      }, 1000);
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<main id="photo_detail">
  <photo-list :photos="photos"></photo-list>
</main>
```